# best way to extract a string from a BATCH of files

Tags: string, batch-file, extract

i have to process 300+ HTML files, extract a string from each one and place it in a separate text file for import downstream.  upside: the string format is identical in each file and is +/- two lines from the same position as well.

i thought maybe using Python, but then i thought PERL might be a better way since this kinda plays to it's backyard.

sadly, i have no access to UNIX/LINUX or i'd just grep it...

this is such an odd client request that i'm a bit goggle-eyed ATM.

so: what is the best way to extract a target string from a BATCH of files?

WR!

Comment: Notepad++! http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ Gotta love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give us more details (i.e. path and name of the files, the string you want to extract, etc) perhaps I may write a Windows Batch .BAT file to achieve this task...

**EDIT**

To write a Batch file that successfully run I need a couple additional data, so I made some assumptions. You may help me to fix the details. This is my method:

1. Seek for a line that contains ">Text link<". I suppose there is just one; this may be fixed.
2. Read the next line. I assumed that each `td` is located in independent lines; this may be fixed.
3. In this line remove the text from beginning of line until `value` string.
4. Replace quotes by $ (the next step cannot process quotes).
5. Get the text between $; this is the result.

`for /F skip...` command may read a wrong line if thefile contains empty lines; this may be fixed.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
findstr /n ">Text link<" thefile.htm > linefound.tmp
for /F "delims=:" %%a in (linefound.tmp) do set lineNo=%%a
for /F "skip=%lineNo% delims=" %%a in (thefile.htm) do (
    set "theLine=%%a"
    goto continue
)
:continue
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set theLine=!theLine:*value=!
set theLine=!theLine:"=$!
for /F "tokens=2 delims=$" %%a in ("!theLine!") do set URL=%%a
echo Result: %URL%
```

**EDIT no. 2**

You are confusing me. Worked the first code or not? The second example you posted in the comments seems not be related to the first one (is the data within second `<td>` or after `[url=http://`?). Is it the same problem or a different one? Please, don't assume I know about HTML file format (I don't). I DO know about Batch files, but I can't guess what to do if I have not complete details...

The following Batch file show everything between square brackets that comes IN THE SAME LINE that have the `[url=http://` string in the file given in the first parameter:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('findstr /n "[url=http://" %1') do echo %%a
```

Comment: path would be any local folder.  the files are old HTML files from which they want to extract old URLs.  i know.  i looked at them blankly too... anyway. the URL is *always* within a second `<td>` following one that contains the text "Text link".  here's an example:
   
 <td style="width:20%">Text link</td>
 <td>
     <input type="text" class="text" value="http://www.someSite.com/somepath/andSoForth" readonly />
 </td>
   
hope that helps.  a BAT would be lovely!!  :D  thank you!

Comment: also: for what it's worth, the data they want is usually around lines 1030-1035 of each file.  don't know if that's useful, but it may be if you can direct the BAT to skip to line 1020 and start searching there, stopping by line 1040....

Comment: :(  no bat?  :'(  thanks anyhoo.  i'll see if i can get one elsewhere.

Comment: apologies for delay, out of town.  here's some more data for you:  you can search for this string '[url=http://' because it looks like they have some shortcode in there.  so if you can just target that opening string and extract everything between the square brackets '[blahblah]', that's good enough for my purposes!  you are a wizard and i sacrifice small animals in your honour!  lol.  :D

Comment: actual animals not harmed during utterly fake, non-existent sacrificial process...  :D

Comment: sorry to confuse you.  my last post was an addendum intending to give you more specific information to work with.  :)  i'll give the new script a shot.  does it output to a text file?  in a beautiful reversal, i know nothing about batch files and a lot about HTML.  lol.  i'm presuming i just copy this into a text file 'somefile.bat' and run it in the directory with all the HTML files.  is that correct?

Comment: nice.  it works well enough that i can carve the rest up in Notepad++.  i wasn't sure where the second batch statement was supposed to go...but i think i can deconstruct the batch enough to get exactly what i'm wanting.  thank you very very much.  can you recommend a good learning resource for batch files?  thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As you're already familiar with Grep, why not use a Windows port, such as the [Grep in GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)?

Comment: ooh! sweet!  i'll look into that too.  :)

Comment: meh.  bit of a hassle to get going.  the batch file works a heck of a lot better in this instance.  slick and fast.  thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Another great way to get a ton of *nix functionality in Windows is Cygwin [http://www.cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com/)